# Adding td to a specific tr dynamically and being able to remove the td

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have the following code listing I am working on. I would like to add as many more textareas in a specific table cell. Each cell can have many individual textareas which I add with jQuery or remove. When I click add, it adds but when I click remove, it takes off a complete table row, then again if I click the second row to add textareas there it adds the textareas to the top row. What am I missing?

```
<html>
    <head>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                var addDiv = $('#addinput');
                var i = $('#addinput td').size() + 1;

                $('#addNew').live('click', function() {
                    $('<tr><td><textarea  id="p_new" rows="1" cols="10" name="data[]" value="" placeholder="I am New" ></textarea><a href="#" id="remNew"><img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>img/remove.png" alt="x" width="15px" height="15px"></a><td> </tr>').appendTo(addDiv);
                    i++;

                    return false;
                });

                $('#remNew').live('click', function() {
                    if( i > 2 ) {
                        $(this).parents('td').remove();
                        i--;
                    }
                    return false;
                });
            });

        </script>

    </head>
    <body>       

        <table border="1">
            <tr>

            <td id="addinput">
                <textarea  id="p_new" rows="1" cols="10" name="data[]" value="" placeholder="Input Value" ></textarea><a href="#" id="addNew"><img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>img/add.png" alt="+" width="15px" height="15px"></a>
            </td>
            </tr>
               <tr>           
            <td>
                <textarea  id="p_new" rows="1" cols="10" name="data[]" value="" placeholder="Input Value" ></textarea><a href="#" id="addNew"><img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>img/add.png" alt="+" width="15px" height="15px"></a>
            </td>
            </tr>

        </table>       

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Couple things right away: what version of jQuery are you using (`live` is deprecated in newer versions), also, you have repeating ID's on elements, stop that. ID's should be unique, this WILL cause problems when you are targeting these elements via ID.

Answer (score 1):

`Live` is not supported with jQuery 1.9.1

Use `on` to attach delegated events instead

```
 $('#remNew').live('click', function() {
 $('#addNew').live('click', function () {
```

Should be

```
 $('table').live('click', '.remNew', function() {

 $('table').live('click', '.addNew', function() {
```

**ID is supposed to be unique on a HTML page.**

So replace it **with a class instead..**

Your `HTML` should be something like this

```
<textarea  class="p_new" rows="1" cols="10" name="data[]" value=""
      placeholder="I am New" >
</textarea>

<a href="#" class="remNew">
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HWz9X/)**

Comment: ID's on OP's `<tr>` tags are also repeating, the code is also appending a new `tr` inside a `td` each time the new row button is clicked.

Comment: @tymeJV.. just observed that .. Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot for that, but what of the lower row, it would be great if it was creating its own like the upper row, thanks tho

Comment: For the 2nd row change `<a href="#" class="addNew">` to `<a href="#" class="remNew">`